# ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(PARANOID) is not producing resource leak logs

Tags: java, netty

I have a netty 4 http server Implemented.

```
public void start() {
    System.out.println("In Start method");
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new HttpServerPipelineFactory())
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_WATER_MARK, WriteBufferWaterMark.DEFAULT)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(listenerPort).sync();
        System.out.println("server started listening on port " + listenerPort);
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

HTTP pipeline factory class is -

```
public class HttpServerPipelineFactory extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast("compress", new HttpContentCompressor());
        pipeline.addLast("decompress", new HttpContentDecompressor());
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator( 512 * 1024));
        pipeline.addLast("chunked", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("flow", new FlowControlHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("keep-alive", new HttpServerKeepAliveHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("request", new AdvancedHTTPHandler());
    }
}
```

AdvancedHTTPHandler is -

```
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH;
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.OK;
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1;
import static io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8;

public class AdvancedHTTPHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HTTPRequestHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest request) {
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, Unpooled.copiedBuffer("My Netty".getBytes()), false);
        response.headers().add(request.headers());
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        ctx.read();
    }
}
```

In the Main.java -

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(PARANOID);
            HttpServer server = new HttpServer(5020);
            server.start();
        }
    }
```

As you see in the Main application, I've set `ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(PARANOID);` but I don't see any resource leak detection logs in my application logs.

what is that I'm missing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Nope that's different issue

Comment: You don't produce any logs, so you assume the flag doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any leaks in your code so it makes sense that there is no leak reported. Just replace `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` with `ChannelInboundHandlerAdaptor` or call `request.retain()` in your `channelRead0(...)` method and you will see a report.

Comment: Tried those changes suggested by you. Still not able to see the logs.